# SAML2 Authentication extension for CKAN

Tags: saml-2.0, ckan

Can someone explain Saml2 authentication process? I have installed ckanext-saml2 extension for ckan.I have a extra button in login form which is called login with sso.But I donot have any sp metadata(sp.xml).Also I have idp.xml but what should I write to the this file.Do you have any idea about these files?Should I create a sp.xml file?Also should I change idp.xml file?When I click the button where should I read user information ?

Comment: During the install instructions it has some bullets on this. `Place your identity provider's idp.xml metadata here: ckanext/saml2/config/` and `Generate the sp metadata (sp.xml): /usr/lib/ckan/bin/python /usr/lib/ckan/src/pysaml2/tools/make_metadata.py /usr/lib/ckan/src/ckanext-saml2/ckanext/saml2/config/sp_config.py > sp.xml (the paths to python, make_metadata.py sp_config.py might vary depending on where you installed ckan in your virtual env)`. Checkout the readme https://github.com/DataShades/ckanext-saml2#ckanext-saml2. Also, I'd suggest reading up on Saml2 and review the ext. codebase.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change the **idp.xml**.

Basically **ckanext-saml2** is used to allow Users to enter CKAN portal from other places, rather than only CKAN.

In order to do that, you'll need an **idp.xml** and **sp.xml** files.

**idp.xml** - file that consists of a unique path to the remote Portal where all Users already exists (usually it marked as **entityID**) and [X509 Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

**sp.xml** - file that is generated by CKAN portal and has pretty much same data as the **idp.xml**.

Both of those files are used to allow Users to log in into CKAN from other portals. In other words, **sp.xml** file is provided to the IdP (Identity Provider) and the **idp.xml** file is provided to the CKAN portal (Service Provider) that is going to use it.

According to the **ckanext-saml2** documentation, all configuration should be done in **ckanext/saml2/config/sp_config.py** file. Configuration should consist **entityID** URL from **idp.xml**, path to the **idp.xml** file, path to logs, data about the CKAN portal, fields that should be taken from the response, their mapping and so on...

After the configuration done, according to documentation, you will be able to generate the **sp.xml** from the **sp_config.py** file by using **python make_metadata.py sp_config.py**.

The button on the login page should redirect you to the IdP login page, where you should log in and be redirected back to CKAN. CKAN will automatically create a User for you if it not exists on the CKAN Portal using the response from the IdP.

For more details, you can check out the [Datashades SAML2 CKAN repo](https://github.com/datashades/ckanext-saml2) or at the original once.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure about SSO then you need to have a good reading about that.

Can you tell us what kind of IdP you integrate with? AD FS?

Your sp.xml should be generated by the ckanext-saml2 extension, have a look their git hub page. Then you need to upload sp.xml (sp metadata to your IdP)